# Can I setup an MX record for a particular user email address?

Tags: domain, email-server, mx-record

I would like to configure 2 MX records : 
- One MX record that identifies an email server to the domain @mycompany.com that will handle all of the emails except one email
- Another MX Record that will redirect to another email server if the address email is: me@mycompany.com

Is it possible? If yes, how can I achieve it?

Thanks,

Fabien

Answer (score 16):

You can't do this by indicating multiple the MX records for the same (sub)domain. The mail will be delivered to the server(s) defined by your MX record regardin **only** the (sub)domain, without any look at the user@... Mail routing is done on the (sub)domain part only.

Possible solutions :

- You can use subdomains, to re-route easily : me@sub.domain.com . The drawback is that you have to change your email address and ask your contacts to update theirs.
- However, there's nothing stopping that mail server being an application that forwards mail onto several other servers based on the user name of the recipient... i.e. tell your mail client to forward all incoming messages for me@domain.com to an other mail server.

Comment: Any example of an specific mail server that could act as some sort of proxy that could send certain messages to server A or B depending on the recipient?.

Comment: Thanks Kami; would that email relay service, given that the email is signed by DKIM, wouldn't break the DKIM?

Answer (score 4):

No. The MX record for a domain designates the SMTP server/s which are responsible for receiving mail for the whole domain.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you *can* designate an alternate MX record for subdomain.mycompany.com to handle mail sent to you@subdomain.mycompany.com.

If you are trying to establish a secondary e-mail address for specific messages/alerts to be delivered if/when your primary mail server is down, this may meet your needs.  But, I'm just speculating: it would be helpful to understand the reason why you want to designate an alternate MX record for a specific address.